# "Method Not Implemented" error - Firefox 3

Tags: http

Getting sporadic errors from users of a CMS; Ajax requests sometimes result in a "501 Method not implemented" response from the server. Not all the time; usually works.

Application has been stable for months. Users seem to be getting it with Firefox 3. I've seen a couple references via Google to such problems being related to having "charset=UTF-8" in the Content-type header, but these may be spurious

Has anyone seen this error or have any ideas about what the cause could be?

Thanks

Ian

Comment: Anything new on that problem?

Comment: I have had the same problem, it seems to be when un put huge chunk of data on one `$_POST` or `$_GET` or it could be an encoding error; eitherway its annoying :)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check the logs of the server to see what's causing the issue. For example, it might be that these requests are garbled, say, because of a flaw in the HTTP 1.1 persistent connection implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

1. Try clearing your cookies and your cache
2. Type about:config into the URL bar, list of configuration settings for Firefox
3. Locate the setting for 'network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris'
4. Set the value of names of the servers to use NTLM with.
5. Locate the setting for 'network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris'
6. Set the value of names of the servers to use NTLM with.
7. network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-proxies = True
8. Restart Firefox - Test URL to application

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs as your app is not running on the same domain as your service. You need to configure your Server to accept those calls by adding the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header.